# configure wxFreeChart problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: compiling, configure

I have problem with configure

```
petat@UNUC:~/Plocha/wxFreeChart-master$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for the --enable-debug option... will be automatically detected
checking for the --enable-unicode option... will be automatically detected
checking for the --enable-shared option... will be automatically detected
checking for the --with-toolkit option... will be automatically detected
checking for the --with-wxshared option... will be automatically detected
checking for the --with-wxversion option... will be automatically detected
checking for wx-config... /usr/bin/wx-config
checking for wxWidgets version >= 2.8.0... yes (version 3.1.1)
checking for wxWidgets static library... no
checking if wxWidgets was built with UNICODE enabled... yes
checking if wxWidgets was built in DEBUG mode... no
checking if wxWidgets was built in STATIC mode... no
checking which wxWidgets toolkit was selected... configure: error: 
        Cannot detect the currently installed wxWidgets port !
        Please check your 'wx-config --cxxflags'...
```

If I compile this next code on comand line all is ok

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class Simple : public wxFrame
{
public:
    Simple(const wxString& title)
        : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, 150))
    {
        Centre();
    }
};

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit()
    {
        Simple *simple = new Simple(wxT("Simple"));
        simple->Show(true);
        return true;
    }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

with

```
g++ basic.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs std,aui ` -std=gnu++11 -o program
```

Comment: Could you please add a link to wxFreeChart repository? How does it possible that you have wx 3.1.1 on 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

You should install all necessary build tools with

```
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-dev libwxbase3.0-dev build-essential
```

and then retry.